# Use third-party embed code in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, embed

I need to use a third part embed code for a form. I'm trying to return it in a component, but it's obviously not working. How can I set this one up?

```
class Form extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div id="apply_form">
          <a name="form" id="formAnchor"></a>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://fs22.formsite.com/include/form/embedManager.js?1605047845"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          EmbedManager.embed({
            key: "key",
            width: "100%",
            mobileResponsive: true
          });
          </script>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's not a really clean way of doing this, short of reaching into the DOM to insert the external script, then running the embed code directly.

Here's how I'd go about this:

```
class Form extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute(
      'src', 
      'https://fs22.formsite.com/include/form/embedManager.js?1605047845');
    script.addEventListener('load', () => {
      EmbedManager.embed({
        key: "key",
        width: "100%",
        mobileResponsive: true
      });
    });
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="apply_form">
          <a name="form" id="formAnchor"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! and cleared things up for me.

Comment: I have an issue now - when I add it to the page with import and then <Form/> the console shows an error -  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null - any idea why?

Comment: No idea; it's probably specific to this embed script. You could try swapping the `addEventListener` and `appendChild` lines; perhaps it's trying to read the DOM positioning of the `<script>` element.